# iOS 16 can not change orientation correctly when other window exists

Tags: uikit, screen-orientation, ios16, uiwindowscene

On iOS16, when force rotating the screen with the new API `requestGeometryUpdate:errorHandler:` to force rotation of the screen, if there are other UIWindow on the top of the current screen, the rotation will only take effect on the top window. Is this a bug in iOS16? How to resolve this?

[image]
[image]